# Passing a variable to subview as @Binding from a @Query array

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, cloudkit

I have a main view in my app, that gets a array of items from CloudKit by query. I then use a foreach to show a list of items. Now, if I create the "row" inside the list and I update data on another device, the list gets updated with new data.

But if I create a subview of the "row", it doesn’t. I’ve tried searching all over Stack and Google, but everywhere the original array of items is a @State variable and then the contents are already @Binding. But if I go via @Query, I cannot figure out, how to pass on the items to the subview as @Binding.

This way works perfectly:

```
struct ItemsView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query(sort: [SortDescriptor(\Item.name)) private var items: [Item]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        NavigationLink {
                            EditView(item: item)
                        } label: {
                            EmptyView()
                        }
                        HStack(spacing: 8) {
                                Image(systemName: "photo.circle.fill")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .scaledToFit()
                                    .frame(width: 48, height: 48)
                                    .opacity(0.08)
                            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                Text(item.name).font(.body)
                                if let desc = item.description,
                                   !desc.isEmpty {
                                    Text(desc).font(.footnote)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But if I split it into a separate subview, the view does not get updated if the data changes.

```
struct ItemsView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query(sort: [SortDescriptor(\Item.name)) private var items: [Item]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        NavigationLink {
                            EditView(item: item)
                        } label: {
                            EmptyView()
                        }
                        ItemRow(item: item)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ItemRow: View {
    var item: Item
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 8) {
            Image(systemName: "photo.circle.fill")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(width: 48, height: 48)
                .opacity(0.08)
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(item.name).font(.body)
                if let desc = item.description,
                   !desc.isEmpty {
                    Text(desc).font(.footnote)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried using @Binding in subview, but then I get an error, that `item` is not Binding. I also tried casting item to @Bindable as in one example inside the foreach (`@Bindable var item = item`), but this doesn’t wor either and doesn’t compile.

I’m on XCode 15 and iOS 17.

Comment: Did you try `@Bindable var item` for the property in ItemRow?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes, I did. That didn’t help unfortunately.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Yes, that for some reason doesn’t work either – then I get an error in the parent view "Cannot reference invalid declaration 'item'"

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `@Binding` with a `@Query` because `Binding` is by definition a two-way connection with a value type and `Query` is read-only.

If you want to edit an `Item` you have to change `ItemRow` to

```
struct ItemRow: View {
    @Bindable var item: Item
```

now you can access

```
$item.someProperty
```

so you can edit.

If you have autoSave enabled then SwiftData will save the `modelContext` eventually if not you should call `modelContext.save()` the `Query` will get the new values because it is always listening to the store for changes.

Comment: I don’t want to "edit" the items, I want them to update in the list when the data changes in the background. The problem is, that in the ItemRow is extracted into a subview, the values are not updated on the fly in the list. If the row is inline as in my first example, the rows change immediately when I change data on another device.

Comment: @margusholland make sure you are saving the `modelContext`you cant update `Query` directly it has to be through the context.

Comment: I am saving the model and as I said, it works perfectly if the HStack is added directly inside the List, but doesn’t if I add it as a subview. If I go into my edit view, the data has been updated in the background and it’s all there.

Comment: @margusholland I would submit a bug report, I had a similar issue with Map and the other way to overcome was with `id` is a a dirty workaround but something is something.